# WPF Borderless window is maximized only to primary screen size

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0, windows-7-x64

I have a problem with multimonitor system and maximizing my borderless WPF C# .NET 4.0 window. One monitor is 1680x1050 (primary) and the second is 1920x1080 (secondary). When I'm maximizing my window on the primary screen - no problems, even when I switch the order of those two. But every time I'm trying to maximize it on the secondary screen it's being cut off to the size of primary monitor. I see that the window size is given appropriate but this doesn't work.

Getting the size of monitor:

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.Screen GetCurrentScreen()
    {
        System.Drawing.Point centerPoint = new System.Drawing.Point((int)(Left + Width / 2), (int)(Top + Height / 2));
        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Screen s in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
        {
            if (s.Bounds.Contains(centerPoint)) 
            {
                return s;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Maximizing:

```
    private void Maximize
    {
        if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
        {
            var scr = GetCurrentScreen();

            //this.MaxHeight = scr.WorkingArea.Height;
            //this.MaxWidth = scr.WorkingArea.Width;

            if (scr != null)
            {
                if (scr.Primary)
                {
                    this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
                    this.MaxWidth = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.MaxHeight = double.PositiveInfinity; //even ridiculous values don't work
                    this.MaxWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;
                    this.Height = scr.WorkingArea.Height; // correct values of 2nd screen
                    this.Width = scr.WorkingArea.Width;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.MaxHeight = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeight;
                this.MaxWidth = SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidth;
            }

            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
```

What I get is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLsPi.jpg

What I want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI5IO.jpg

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just using `this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;` *instead* of all the manual code to resize the `Window`?

Comment: Yup I tried, but still the same.

Comment: There is a possibility that some of your code is causing this issue as I cannot replicate it on my two screens... they are both the same size, but if I change the resolution on one the application still maximises correctly. If you start a new WPF Application and just add `WindowState = "Maximized"` to the `Window` declaration, do you *still* have the same problem?

Comment: You're right. In a new WPF Application problem doesn't occur, so there's something wrong with my code. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'll just put that comment into an answer so that this question can be marked as answered. Please come back and ask another question here once you have found out a little more about this 'new' problem if you are still unable to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility that some of your code is causing this issue as I cannot replicate it on my two screens... they are both the same size, but if I change the resolution on one, the application still maximises correctly. If you start a new WPF Application and just add

```
WindowState = "Maximized"
```

to the Window declaration, do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Thanks for help. I've manipulated the size of my window in other place and that was the case. But without Your tip I wouldn't find it and fix it.

Comment: You're welcome... this is easily and frequently done.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me last time I had to maximize a window on my secondary screen:

```
Screen sTwo = Screen.AllScreens[1];
this.Top = sTwo.Bounds.Top;
this.Left = sTwo.Bounds.Left;
this.Width = sTwo.Bounds.Width;
this.Height = sTwo.Bounds.Height;
```

Make sure you add the reference

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

And set

```
AllowsTransparency="True"
```

in your *.xaml

Answer (score 0):

Try to override or correct ArrangeOverride method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.arrangeoverride.aspx

> When overridden in a derived class, positions child elements and
>   determines a size for a FrameworkElement derived class

Symptoms are similar.